# Why does this multi-line shell script not work using cygwin, although in one line it works?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, sh

I use cygwin for Windows to run shell scripts. My script changes umlauts to LaTeX equivalents. It works.

I run the script via:

```
sh umlauts.sh
pause
```

**This is my sed command, which perfectly works.**

```
/usr/bin/find -name \*.tex | xargs -I p sed -i 's/ü/{\\"u}/g' p
```

However, running it twice in the same file leads to an error:

```
/usr/bin/find -name \*.tex | xargs -I p sed -i 's/ü/{\\"u}/g' p
/usr/bin/find -name \*.tex | xargs -I p sed -i 's/ä/{\\"a}/g' p
```

I get:

```
: no such file or directory.tex
```

Which looks like a strangely formatted message, as .tex is the ending of my file and should not be part of the error message.

**This is probably a very trivial error. Why can't I write multiple lines of code into my script and run it successfully?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script was written with a DOS editor and contains `\r\n` line endings. *nix (including cygwin) uses `\n` line endings, so the `\r` character remains at the end of the sed `p` command.

See if you have `dos2unix` available, or run this command on the script

```
sed 's/\r$//' umlauts.sh
```

Comment: Oh no! I thought that I wouldn't fall for that again. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Also avoid spaces after the backslash \ (trailing spaces), somehow it causes problems with my Cygwin. Luckily I did not have to use Windows after 2016.